# Javascript array loop variable undefined

Tags: javascript

I am having a bit of trouble with a loop that reads an array:

```
var myStringArray = [{
  "people": [{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "name 1"
  }, {
    "id": "456",
    "name": "name 2"
  }]
}];

var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {            
  console.log(myStringArray[i].id);
}
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: You're not going deep enough... `myStringArray[0].people[i].id`. ;)

Comment: and `var arrayLength = myStringArray[0].people.length`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over the inner array(`people` property of the first element in the main array).

```js
var myStringArray = [{
  "people": [{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "name 1"
  }, {
    "id": "456",
    "name": "name 2"
  }]
}];
var arrayLength = myStringArray[0].people.length;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  console.log(myStringArray[0].people[i].id);
}
```

---

Although you can use **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method.

```js
var myStringArray = [{
  "people": [{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "name 1"
  }, {
    "id": "456",
    "name": "name 2"
  }]
}];

myStringArray[0].people.forEach(function(v) {
  console.log(v.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Access id from object stored in myStringArray[0].

Here is the modified code:-

```
var myStringArray = [
    {
        "people":[
            {"id":"123","name":"name 1"},
            {"id":"456","name":"name 2"}
        ]
    }
];

var array = myStringArray[0].people,
    arrayLength = array.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

    console.log(array[i].id);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

because your array only haw 1 item and its people.
and people don't has id property. the people contains two item that every one has their id.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < myStringArray[i].length; j++)
  {
    console.log(myStringArray[i][j].id);
  } 
}
```